# Installation of travis fails on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I'm trying to install travis on ubuntu but keeps failing. How can I solve this?

```
sudo gem install travis
```

> Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing travis:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20180216-3916-17dbwfe.rb extconf.rb
>   checking for ffi.h... no checking for ffi.h in
>   /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no checking for shlwapi.h... no
>   checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes checking for
>   rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes checking for
>   rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes creating extconf.h creating
>   Makefile
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c make
>   "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c make
>   "DESTDIR=" Running autoreconf for libffi
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi/autogen.sh: 2:
>   exec: autoreconf: not found libffi.mk:6: recipe for target
>   '"/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a' failed make: ***
>   ["/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 127
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/ffi-1.9.21/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running the following command.

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```